# Question regarding books for commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

So I was searching about books for commutative algebra. I have read most of the algebra namely galois theory and field theory and basic algebra from Dummit Foote. So I was thinking about studying commutative algebra from Dummit Foote. Although most of the suggestion I have seen for the book for commutative algebra is Atiyah Mcdonald. So it will be great if anyone can tell me how well commutative algebra is written in Dummit Foote.

Comment: D&F is a good book for beginners, but it's too verbose to be a reference book. They do treat valuation rings, integral extensions, localisation, and Zariski topology, which I think are very good subjects for a first course in commutative algebra. But IIRC they don't talk about Krull dimension. Atiyah--McDonald is great. My personal favorite is Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry". Everything is in there!

Comment: But the thing is I don't have much exposure to topology. And I have heard eisenbud has application of topology very much. That's why I was reluctant

Comment: Maybe you can learn them hand-in-hand. You've seen basic ring theory, so you should be somewhat ready. Topology and commutative rings are inextricable, as Eisenbud shows.

Answer (score 0):

May be its a bit late to comment,but you can go through Basic Commutative Algebra by Dr. Balwant Singh. It is a great commutative algebra book and also covers some interesting topics in Homological Algebra. Dummit and Foote is a great book in its own right but certain things like resolutions, category theory, derived functors are well written in Balwant Singh book.

Comment: Balwant sing, are you somehow from cmi?

Comment: No no I am not from CMI, but you can give it a look.( the book) if you find it worthwhile let me know.

Comment: No actually a prof who was extremely close with the author exactly told me this book,  and as you have said that book along with a book by Gopalakrishnan is really good for commutative algebra. That's why I thought.

Comment: Ah I see , actually I am doing PhD under Balwant sir's student. So my supervisor advised me to go through that book.

Comment: Ohh okay okay that's why, what's his name if you don't mind.

Comment: Ohh sorry his prof told me about the book hahaha, I really didn't notice it before. R, Shridharan told me about his book

Answer (score 0):

Dummit and Foote is actually a pretty decent book to learn commutative algebra though I have found that not many people recommend it. It treats basic commutative algebra(including computational aspects of Grobner bases, primary decomposition), affine algebraic geometry(Spec, Zariski topology, Nullstellensatz, localization etc.) and does a decent job of introducing homological algebra. However, I think in regards to certain topics like exact sequences, Hom-Tensor adjunction, Atiyah-Macdonald and Eisenbud's books had more interesting exercises. Another resource which is woefully underappreciated as a reference to commutative algebra is the Stacksproject, chapter 10. Like Eisenbud, it probably contains far too many things that are irrelevant if one has the intention to gain the prerequisites to start learning algebraic geometry but they are still useful references.